# Autocomplete on TextArea not respected

Tags: autocomplete, textarea

This is pretty bizarre, but according to the MDN docs autocomplete has wide-spread support for TextArea element (given that the listed requirements are met):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete

But it doesn't seem to work, at least not in either Chrome or FireFox.

This is an example of what doesn't work:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="index.html" method="post">
            <input type="first" name="input" id="a" autocomplete="on"><br> <!-- Works! -->
            <textarea name="second" id="b" autocomplete="on"></textarea><br> <!-- Doesn't work!-->
            <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

So this begs the question: has there been an actual regression in two major browsers, or are the MDN docs wrong? ... or am I missing something entirely different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it currently isn't supported from what I can tell: https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5680387573415936